# Bulk API 1.0 - use Workbench

Tags: bulk-api, workbench

How can I use Bulk API 1.0 (for query) with Salesforce Workbench (or Postman) ?

I found that [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_code_curl_walkthrough.htm) explaining Bulk API 1.0 but only with cURL, and I'd like to use Workbench or Postman if possible, but when I use the xml as the body, I got an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bulk API requires a special header, `X-SFDC-Session`, that the other REST API calls don't use (the majority of them use Authorization). As such, to get started, you will need to use the following settings in Workbench:

[image: Example]

Method: POST

URL: /services/async/44.0/job

Request Headers:

```
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/xml
X-SFDC-Session: 00D..........
```

Comment: Thanks, where can I find the X-SFDC-Session ?

Comment: @dou You get it by running an executeAnonymous script, such as: `system.assert(false, userinfo.getsessionid());`, or you can grab a different token, such as by calling a login method or something else. I don't see a way to get it directly in the Workbench.